# Total newb having SSH tunnel and remote MySQL access problems

Tags: ssh, remote-access, ssh-tunnel, mysql

I don't often work with linux or need to SSH tunnel into remote MySQL databases, so pardon my ignorance. I'm using Windows 7 and am needing to connect to a remote MySQL instance on a Linux server.

For months I had been using the HeidiSQL client application successfully. Today two things happened: the DB moved to a new server and I updated HeidiSQL, now I cannot log in to the MySQL server, when attempting I get this message from Heidi:

```
SQL Error (2003) in statement #0: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

If I use Putty, I can connect to the server and get MySQL access through command line, including fetching data from the DB. I assume this means my credentials and address are correct, but do not understand why putting those same details into HeidiSQL's SSH tunnel info won't work. I also downloaded the MySQL Workbench and attempted to set up a connection through that client and got this message:

```
Cannot Connect to Database Server

Your connection attempt failed for user 'myusername' from your host to server at localhost:3306:
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

Please:
1 Check that mysql is running on server localhost
2 Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
3 Check the myusername has rights to connect to localhost from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines) 
4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for localhost connecting from the host address you're connecting from
```

From Googling around I see that it could be related to the MySQL bind-address, but I am a third party sub-contractor with no access to the MySQL settings of this box and the system admin is assuring me that I'm an idiot and need to figure it out on my end. This is completely possible but I don't know what else to try.

**Edit 1 - The client settings I am using**

In Heidi and MySQL Workbench I am using the following:

**SSH host + port:** theHostnameOfTheRemoteServer.com:22  {this is the same host I can Putty to}

**SSH Username:** mySSHusername  {the same user name I use for my Putty connection}

**SSH Password:** mySSHpassword {the same password for the Putty connection}

**Local port:** 3307  {this is on the SSH settings tab and was defaulted to 3307 by Heidi, changing it to 3306 gives me a different error: SQL Error (1045) in statement #0: Access denied for user 'mySQLusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"}

**MySQL host:** theHostnameOfTheRemoteServer.com {consensus seems to be I should use 'localhost' here}

**MySQL User:** mySQLusername {which I can connect with once in with Putty}

**MySQL Password:** mySQLpassword {which works once in with Putty}

**Port:** 3306

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in this case I was able to get the sys admin to go back and doublecheck and it turned out to be permissions after all, but I sincerely thank everyone who helped me exhaust my own troubleshooting so I could go back to him fairly confident the problem was not on my end.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the `bind-address=` in `/etc/my.conf`, under `[mysqld]`, is set to the new server IP address.

Second, you'll need to make sure your user still has access to connect to MySQL remotely from whatever IP address you're attempting to remotely connect from.

Run the following query from the MySQL command line where 'username' is the user name you're attempting to log in with and 'ipaddress' is the IP address you're attempting to connect from.

`SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'ipaddress';`

If you don't get any valid results from the above query, then you need to grant access to your user at the IP address that you're attempting to connect remotely from. You can do this by running a query like the one below.

`GRANT ALL PRIVILGES TO 'username'@'ipaddress' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';`

Also, make sure you're connecting to the correct port set in `/etc/my.cnf`. If it is not explicitly set by `port=` in `my.cnf`, then it uses the default port of `3306`. You can also check the port that MySQL is running on in the MySQL command line by running the query below.

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'port';`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't think I have access to view the bind-address. I am able to connect to the mySQL server through putty using command line. If I'm not mistaken, and based on the error messages I'm getting, the 'ipaddress' in your example should be 'localhost' since I appear to be getting SSH access fine. Running SHOW GRANTS FOR 'mySQLusername'@'localhost' shows two records: "GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'mySQLusername'@'localhost'" and "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'myDatabase'.* TO 'mySQLusername'@'localhost'"

Comment: If you're remotely connecting to MySQL, the IP address needs to be the  IP address that you're connecting from, not localhost. It operates on a separate port and protocol from SSH. Localhost would only possibly be applicable if you had a direct VPN connection to that server.

Comment: So when I am getting the error message "SQL Error (1045) in statement #0: Access denied for user 'mySQLusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" from the SQL client, what is it referring to when it says 'localhost'?

Comment: I guess I should have read some of your other comments about you using an SSH tunnel to connect to the server. Since that's the case, and you're still getting an error, make sure you're using the correct password (which I'm sure you've already checked). The main problem is most likely that you just have `USAGE` privileges, [which is basically "no privileges"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_usage). Try granting more access, like `SELECT` on the database you need to access remotely, and `SHOW DATABASES` if you need it.

Comment: Thanks. There are two records in the table, usage is on star dot star, ALL PRIVILEGES is granted on the database that I can successfully access through putty and command line, but not with a SQL client.

Comment: Are you specifying that specific database that you have `ALL PRIVILEGES` on when you're connecting, or are you just trying to connect without specifying a database? If you're not specifying a database, you'll need more privileges, like `SHOW DATABASES`. Otherwise, try specifying the database *(a.k.a. Schema in MySQL)* you have privileges on .

Comment: I am defining the database on which I have all privileges as my default schema in my SQL client connection settings, would that be the same thing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11429/discussion-between-nojak-and-kscott)

Answer (score 0):

your heidi mysql client is attempting to connect to "localhost", not the remote mysq.

replace the server addr in heidi config to the IP address or hostname you put in your putty client when you shell in.

> the system admin is assuring me that I'm an idiot and need to figure it out on my end

1o1

Comment: Thanks for replying. Nowhere in my Heidi settings am I putting 'localhost', I am using the remote URL.

Comment: localhost is the default.  you will need to override

Comment: I have values in every field (added to my question) of the connection settings on the Heidi and MySQL Workbench clients, leaving nothing as default. Is this something I need to override in a config file usually?

Comment: didnt realize you were ssh tunnel'ing..... localhost is correct in this case....so, as stated, make it:  MySQL host: localhost..... also, i would look at this setting ===> Local port: 3307

Comment: If I change the Local port from 3307 to 3306 I instead get this message: "SQL Error (1045) in statement #0: Access denied for user 'mySQLusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: excellent, so now go back to root mysql shell, and run a "grant all on [databasename].* to 'mySQLusername'@'localhost' identified by '[yurpasswd]'; flush privileges;"

Comment: I don't have access to the mysql root user, when I attempt to execute the grant all command line the response is "ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'mySQLusername'@'localhost' to database 'databasename'"

Comment: well, at this point, you are successfully talking to mysql, so it is a mysql permissioning issue.  i would ask to verify creds with admin, ask plz, and be nice about it :P

Comment: Just to verify, my inability to connect to MySQL via a client application instead of direct to command line where I am able to connect to the DB and run queries successfully, can be controlled by a MySQL permission? To the MySQL server do my Putty connection and Client App connection look different?

Comment: possibly.  in the mysql permissioning table, there can be a distinction between "127.0.0.1" and "localhost".  you can see this with "use mysql; select user,host from user;".  also, sometimes a host is connected to by hostname, which /etc/hosts may resolve to the ip of the box (instead of localhost).... these can be different cases for mysql permissioning

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've configured your client correctly to point to the new server?  Based on these errors:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'
>
> ...
>
> from your host to server at localhost:3306

it appears you're trying to connect to mysql on your local machine (aka localhost) and not the new server.  If you have the mysql CLI client installed locally, you can test my theory with this:

> mysql -h newservername -u myusername

If that works, you'll be prompted for your password.  Then go back to your GUI client(s) and check your config settings.

Else, make sure you can access the host and that mysql is in fact listening on port 3306 on that host:

> ping -c 4 newservername
>
> telnet newservername 3306

If ping fails, check w/ your friendly sysadmin to confirm 1) the host is up, and 2) ICMP packets aren't blocked.  ping could fail due to firewall rules.

If the host is there, but you can't telnet to 3306, then either that port is restricted or the service isn't running.  Again, verify with a friendly colleauge.  HTH!

Comment: Thanks for your response! Ping succeeds, telent results in a response, but I don't understand it and therefore am not comfortable posting it here. Once I press enter after the string of letters, numbers, and symbols, I get the response "Connection to host lost." So I assume that means I'm making some kind of connection to port 3306

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL host when you SSH in is localhost.  So this:

**MySQL host:** theHostnameOfTheRemoteServer.com

Should be this:

**MySQL host:** localhost

Remember, when you SSH tunnel into anything, the remote host is only a factor for the initial SSH connection. Past that you are essentially “on” the server, so you are now in the realm where you can indeed connect to “localhost.”

EDIT: Also, I am not understanding what the value of setting the local port to 3307 is:

**Local port:** 3307

That should be 3306 unless explicitly changed in some setting somewhere.

**Local port:** 3306

If you can get a connection but a credential error when using 3306 instead of 3307 you are closer to logging in than before! Also, there have been cases where I could not connect to MySQL via `localhost` for odd reasons, so I would connect with the IP address of 127.0.0.1

**MySQL host:** 127.0.0.1

Try that and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for you response, leaving all other settings as in my question and changing the MySQL host to localhost I get the same error message: "SQL Error (2003) in statement #0: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)"

Comment: How about `Local port: 3307`. Why is that there? That seems odd.  Try it with the standard 3306 port instead.

Comment: Changing 3307 to 3306 changes the error to: "SQL Error (1045) in statement #0: Access denied for user 'TheSSHandSQLUsernamesAreFrustratinglyTheSameSoIDon'tKnowWhichThisIs'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: @kscott you realize that the `Access denied for user` is much better that before? With port 3307 you were not getting a connection. Now it is clear you are getting a connection on port 3306, but your credentials are mixed up.  Much closer than before.

Comment: I have double checked that the mySQL credentials I am putting into the client are the same that I am able to successfully use through command line through putty. Setting both ports to 3306 and changing the hostname from localhost to 127.0.0.1 gives me the same error: "SQL Error (1045) in statement #0: Access denied for user 'mySQLuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: Well, you went from `Can't connect to MySQL` to `Access denied for user` which means it’s a MySQL credential issue at this point.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. Are you aware of any extra steps that may be needed for the same credentials that work through command line via putty and plink to be sent through a client? Such as escaping characters, adding quotes, setting character encoding, anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your settings this way:

...

**Local port**: 3307

**MySQL host**: localhost

...

**Port**: 3306

Use non standart ports so, if you are running an instance of MySQL on your local machine, we are sure you are not connecting to it. I don't know HeidiSQL but I think it will tunnel to the default port on the remote server

Comment: Thank you for your response. Changing both Port options to 3307 results in the same error message: "SQL Error (2003) in statement #0: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)"

Comment: Are you using putty or plink for the tunnel? If you are using plink, try connecting once with it from the command line: plink.exe -P 22 -l username remote-host

Comment: Heidi is using plink for the tunnel, I am manually using putty to test my credentials. Using the plink command line, I am able to successfully connect to the server and then also the mysql DB through command line

Comment: Did plink ask you to store the key in cache? If so, try connecting again with HeidiSQL using local port 3307 and port 3306. It seems there's a problem in HeidSQL to manage the first connection to a remote host.

Comment: the plink command line did not mention anything about storing the key in cache, is there a way to explicitly make it do so? Attempting through Heidi again with local 3307 and port 3306 results in error: "SQL Error (2003) in statement #0: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)"

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.caseymclaughlin.com/articles/ssh-tunnels-with-plink-and-heidisql

Comment: Thanks for that, I removed all saved keys from regedit and re-connected with plink, I was prompted to store the key in cache and said yes, but my subsequent attempt to login with Heidi (with local 3307 and port 3306) resulted in the same SQL Error (2003)

Comment: Please check your "Network Type" is "SSH tunnel" in Heidi settings. Try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. Check also if port 3307 on your local machine is blocked  by a firewall or another software. I'm running out of bullets... :D

Comment: I really appreciate the help. SSH Tunnel is selected, I have tried both 127.0.0.1 and localhost, and just turned my firewall completely off, still the same error 2003. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid.